# Why removeObjectsinArray require hash?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

```
- (void)removeObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)otherArray
```

> Removes from the receiving array the objects in another given array.
>   This method is similar to removeObject:, but allows you to efficiently
>   remove large sets of objects with a single operation. If the receiving
>   array does not contain objects in otherArray, the method has no effect
>   (although it does incur the overhead of searching the contents). This
>   method assumes that all elements in otherArray respond to **hash** and
>   isEqual:.

I understand that removeObjectsinArray require isEqual

Why does it need to implement objects either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [NSObject documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html):

> If two objects are equal, they must have the same hash value. This
>   last point is particularly important if you define isEqual: in a
>   subclass and intend to put instances of that subclass into a
>   collection. Make sure you also define hash in your subclass.

If you override `-isEqual:`, it's recommended  to also override `-hash`. So that's the first reason - it would be inconsistent for them not to make the same recommendation in the `-removeObjectsInArray:` documentation.

The second reason is more subtle. As an experienced developer, you could assume `-hash` would not be used for the implementation of `-removeObjectsInArray:` (or find it out by experimentation), and that you can get away with not implementing it on your objects. However, Apple are making clear that they *reserve the right* to use `-hash` in their implementation, if they feel it would be worthwhile optimisation, and that you should implement it just in case.

(I have no clue whether or not they use it in their current implementation)

Comment: It's worth noting that starting with a recent iOS version (6.0?), Apple now uses `-hash` when performing `-removeObjectsInArray:` where they didn't previously. This broke our code because we falsely assumed otherwise, just as you said!